# Склонение числительного

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли в родительном падеже говорить "трехста" вместо "трехсот"? Услышала такое по телевидению и засомневалась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: трехсот. В сложных числительных склоняются оба корня. Хотя в каком-то словаре уже встречала форму трехста с пометой разговорное. Но на радио. по телевидению, в любой официальной речи - только трехсот. Хотя тенденция у числительных к упрощению системы склонения  прослеживается уже давно.

Answer (score 0):

Всё упрощается до именительного падежа. На российском телевидении сказать: более шестисот — это запредельно. Более шестьсот и т. д. и т. п. — это по-нашему.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?